# Google Cloud Run: Packaging multiple app files to one docker image

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am attempting to use Google Cloud Run to create an application which will parse through data and respond with results.

Requirements: 
- Python and a few libraries
- Flask (specially) 
- Will need to read and write to Google Drive or  a Google Storage bucket
- Will need to retrieve data/files to be parsed from an [MyExternalSite] (already have a script for this)

Example workflow:

1. User makes a get request to "https[:]//MyGoogleCloudRunUrl[.]com/MyParameters
2. Google cloud run instance gets triggered with the python script to retrieve data to be parsed using from [MyExternalSite] and using the "MyParameters" to ID which data to retrieve (Already have a script)
3. A second function from the python script parses through the data and results in csv files (Already have a script)
4. A third function creates a directory in gdrive or bucket and dumps the files. (Already have a script)

That is it.

*** Now my question is how can i package all of these individual scripts/applications which have their own directory with configuration files containing urls, credentials etc into one single docker image for use with google cloud run. ***

I have read through google documents but all of the examples and walkthroughs show a basic docker image where a simple "hello world" functions is executed and not something more complex.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to write a `Dockerfile` that installs all the requirements. If you are mostly using Python, start with a `python` image.

Comment: Hi Klaus. I am good with the Dockerfile creation and creating a basic instance to run python successfully. What i am inquiring about is how to add configuration files for services to be used. These configuration files would contain credentials and custom urls from which to retrieve and write to the response data.

Comment: ***Another example*** If i have an application directory "Retrieve from google drive" which contains a gdrive_config.json (credentials and urls), main.py, write.py, read.py... etc. I have the similar structure for other services to be used for this cloud run.  The question, how can i containerize all the different apps into one cloud run instance

Comment: Packaging multiple applications into a single container is often considered to be an anti-pattern, as you need to ensure signal forwarding, flow controls and failure modes of each process. There's a reason why Docker containers have a single entrypoint process and not two or more. :)

Comment: AhmetB, Thanks for your input, makes sense. Do you have an alternative solution advice for the type of workflow that i am looking to accomplish? To note, there are 3 different applications processing/parsing data. They work in a chain, further processing the response from the last. The data format to be ingested never changes.  Additional note is that i have this process working in my system already, but am looking to make it available in the cloud.

Comment: We have something in the works that might help here. I can't say more than stay tuned. :)

Comment: @AhmetB thanks for the heads-up. Will be looking for the news.

Comment: @AhmetB that something in has it come to light. Is it workflows ? I too have a similar requirement like processA(20mins) --> processB(10mins) --> processC(5mins). It's in Python and can flask keep a thread running for such long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert each one of this scrips into a Python function and run them sequentially.

Starting from the python [Quickstart for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#writing):

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    script_1()
    script_2()
    script_3()
    return 'value'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))

def script_1():
   //Code 

def script_2():
  //Code

def script_3():
  //Code
```

Also you will need to add the [python client library for Cloud Storage](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html)  in your `requirements.txt` file.

This is only an example, you can use more complex code organizations [using modules and submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice... will give this a try. 
I was just starting to test a (somewhat) similar approach by creating multiple route options for the different applications.